# DataDog Dashboard False Alarm

Tags: datadog

I had setup a DataDog Dashboard for missing events (Threshold Alert). Below is the query I had used to verify if there is no event within last 10 minutes then send me an alert. Though there is data, sometimes I am getting an alert and when I go back and verify it on the dashboard everything seems to be correct. Am is missing anything from the below query (defining the metric)? or in the Alert conditions

Query: sum(last_10m):sum:Success{prod}.as_count().rollup(sum, 600) <= 0

[image: Set Alert Conditions]